# Relation between condition number of two related matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, condition-number

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, $m_i$ is a $i$-th row of $M$, and $\kappa(M)$ be the ratio between the biggest and the smallest singular values.

We define $N \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d^2}$, where each row of $N$ is defined as $m_im_i^T$ (i.e. the outer product of a row).

What can we say on the condition number of $N$?

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Turning a $d\times d$ matrix into a $1 \times d^2$ row doesn't seem very natural.

Comment: The resulting matrix is $n \times d^2$.. but each row is $d^2$ dimensional.

Comment: If $d^2 > n$, then $N$ is a wide matrix which means that (by the usual definition) $N$ will necessarily have a zero singular value, which means that $\kappa$ will be undefined (or infinite, if you prefer).  Should we consider only the case where $d^2 \leq n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but too long to (conveniently) make into a comment.

In terms of the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), we could say that
$$
N = \pmatrix{
\operatorname{vec}(m_1m_1^T)^T \\
\vdots\\
\operatorname{vec}(m_nm_n^T)^T} = \pmatrix{[m_1 \otimes m_1]^T\\ \vdots \\ [m_n \otimes m_n]^T} = 
\pmatrix{[e_1 \otimes e_1]^T\\
\vdots\\
[e_n \otimes e_n]^T}(M \otimes M)
$$